# Rails: Why does pluck method return uniq values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Account` model with a column `role`. 
I want to select distinct roles by `created_at` date (for example all distinct roles created on 01.01.2018 etc) and get only values of column `role`.
Selection of distinct roles works fine as a query, but when it comes to getting the values, I'm getting unexpected results.

If I'm just using a `map` function on all the query results, everything works good and SQL query looks fine.

```
Account.where(id: 1..10).select(:created_at, :role).distinct.map(&:role)
Account Load (1.0ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "accounts"."created_at", "accounts"."role" FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 10]]
=> ["admin", "manager", "manager", "manager", "manager", "manager", "manager", "manager", "manager"]
```

But if I want to change `.map(&:role)` to `.pluck(:role)`, that are the same by definition, `pluck` method removes first `distinct` condition and leaves only `distinct` by role as we can see in the beginning of the query.

```
Account.where(id: 1..10).select(:created_at, :role).distinct.pluck(:role)
(0.7ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "accounts"."role" FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 10]]
=> ["admin", "manager"]
```

In `pluck` documentation [(apidock)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) it's written, that pluck will use distinct only if the code looks like `.pluck('distinct role')`

Why does it work like this in my case? Is it some undocumented feature?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use select, you can fetch and filter data using `where` and `pluck`, and `where` is preferred over `select` because `select` fetched all the data that you specify from the `database` and iterate over them to filter data at ruby level but using `where` you filter them out at `database` level

Comment: @Subash well, my query is a bit more complex, but in any case I need a select just to select only columns I need from the database. It's a SQL level method that is equal to `SELECT accounts.created_at, accounts.role`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: But the main question is why pluck works this way in my case :)

Comment: Remove the select when using pluck, you'll have the same result. It seems in any way AR improves the query to add an specific attribute when using pluck, this way if passing foo and bar to pluck, you'll get DISTINCT model.foo, model.bar.

Comment: Note if you're working with AR and you need as result an array, you don't need the map, it works, but that's the scenario for pluck.

Comment: @SebastianPalma so the problem is that even if I don't use `.pluck("DISTINCT foo")` it will still apply distinct to the query, overriding my `select.distinct`?

Comment: When using `.select(:created_at, :role).distinct` it does a distinct by those two attributes, in any case, if adding pluck, it'll override that first distinct and use the attribute being specified in the pluck method. Just keep in mind you don't need the select if using pluck in that way `where.select(:created_at, :role).distinct.pluck(:role)` == `where.distinct.pluck(:role)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma strange that it's not really documented.

Comment: "... pluck will use distinct only if ..." - there's no word "only" on that page. I don't see how you got this idea.

Comment: "to change .map(&:role) to .pluck(:role), that are the same by definition" - nooope, they're not the same, not even close. :) `map` is a general-purpose transformation. `pluck` is a modifier in the ActiveRecord query builder.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, my fault. I think I got tricked by the fact that under normal conditions it returns the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question "Why does it work like this in my case?" is because it is supposed to work like this.  You stated:

> In pluck documentation . . . it's written, that pluck will use distinct only if the code looks like `.pluck('distinct role')`

This is not accurate. The doc you referenced shows an example like this as a way to pluck with `DISTINCT`, but does not say that this is the *only* way to apply the `DISTINCT` SQL modifier.  Since you have added `.distinct` onto your `ActiveRecord` relation, the resulting query will be `SELECT DISTINCT`.  This prompts SQL to give you unique values, not the `pluck` method; `pluck` is only returning exactly what your DB gave to it.

For a way to achieve what you are after using `pluck` for distinct combinations of `created_at` and `role`, you can use a `group` instead:

```
Account.where(id: 1..10).group(:created_at, :role).pluck(:role)
# => SELECT "accounts"."role" FROM "accounts" WHERE ("accounts"."id" BETWEEN $1 AND $2) GROUP BY "accounts"."created_at", "accounts"."role"  [["id", 1], ["id", 10]]
```

The `.group(:created_at, :role)` call (which adds a `GROUP BY` SQL clause) will give you unique combinations of rows based on `created_at` and `role` (the same `role` may appear multiple times if it is associated with multiple `created_at` values).  Then `.pluck(:role)` will take only the values for `role`.

Comment: Oh, nice comment about `group by`! I solved my issue by using `map`, but `group by` looks like more proper way in terms of speed.